# Project date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written some Javascript code that spits out an estimated time frame.

For example, right now, it's giving me: 646 days, 5 hours, 13 minutes

Given that info, if I create a new date in Javascript like:

`var d = new Date();`

How do I use the info to project the date in the future?

For example, today is June 30, 2018 and 646 days from now is April 6, 2020. So I'd want to calculate that on page load each time, because the projected date is constantly changing.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, calculate it in total and add the number (as seen in one of post above), else you can do part by part, meaning day part, time part etc, this way you can write your own mini prototype functions to account for all or say most types of date complexities such as daylight savings etc etc. Just to give a fair idea, start with the date.

To do so use [Date.prototype.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), [Date.prototype.setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), [Date.prototype.setMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

```
    var projectEndDate = new Date();
    projectEndDate.setDate(today.getDate()+646);

   // use Date.prototype.setHours(), then
   // Date.prototype.setMinutes() and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the time to today:

```
new Date( Date.now() + ((646 * 24 + 5) * 60 + 13) * 60 * 1000)
```

Or if you want to consider that not every day has 24 hours:

```
const date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 646);
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 5);
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 13);
```

Comment: Remember... not every day is 24 hours in length.  (Daylight savings time, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! In this, could you explain what each thing is doing? 

Sweet, got it working. 

When I output it it shows

"Mon Apr 06 2020 20:39:05 GMT-0500 (CDT)"

How do I convert this to, say, 

`April 6, 2020`

Comment: @jordan the one adds up the milliseconds, the other one sets all values after another. And there are already thousands of solutions for converting a Date to a string, just search for them

Comment: Thanks, looking now but very confused. Will keep searching

Answer (score 1):

[Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) Is by far the best library to use for any date calculation.

```js
let endDate = moment().add({
  d:646, //days
  h: 5, //hours
  m: 13
}).format('MMMM D, YYYY')
document.write(endDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```